# Error msg installing and updating Skype in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, skype

Problem  Solved! Thanks!

I get an error msg when I try to install Skype.

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
kp@kp-Satellite-C660D:~$ apt-get update
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

I have just updated to Ubuntu 14.04 and had error msg's during upgrade.

I'm a newbie and not good at this.. can anyone help?

Many Thanks

Comment: Try doing it with sudo.  `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: try installing skype with the package they provide at their own website

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `apt-get update` make it `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: When I do I get this error msg

Comment: W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems

Answer (score 0):

Run :

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock && sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock && sudo apt-get update
```

If this not solve the problem, then run:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Find the duplicate lines of `http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner i386 Packages` and add `#` at infront of one of them.

Comment: There is no line that includes the end trustry/partner ...

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: There is no line such as the one you mention.

Comment: I keep getting this error:E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?